# Rviz Marker LINE_STRIP is not displayed

Tags: ros, rospy, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello :)

```
   marker_pub = rospy.Publisher('visualization_marker', Marker, queue_size=100)
   line_color = ColorRGBA()       # a nice color for my line (royalblue)
   line_color.r = 0.254902
   line_color.g = 0.411765
   line_color.b = 0.882353
   line_color.a = 1.0
   start_point = Point()        #start point
   start_point.x = 0.2
   start_point.y = 0.0
   start_point.z = 0.2
   end_point = Point()        #end point
   end_point.x = 0.7
   end_point.y = 0
   end_point.z = 0.2

   marker3 = Marker()
   marker3.id = 3
   marker3.header.frame_id = 'world'
   marker3.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP
   marker3.ns = 'Testline'
   marker3.action = 0
   marker3.scale.x = 0.1
   marker3.points.append(start_point)
   marker3.points.append(end_point)
   marker3.colors.append(line_color)
   marker3.colors.append(line_color)

   marker_pub.publish(marker3)
```

the above code should display a simple static line between two points. it is coded in python.
the code seems okay and i added the correct marker in rviz, which displays me the correct namespace set in the code.
even if i remove all the color code: no line appears :(
in an other rviz scene i succesfully added two spheres, so iam wondering whats wrong here.

any help to my suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203782/rviz-marker-line_strip-is-not-displayed/) by [hammel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21716/hammel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-25**:
Try setting `pose.orientation.w = 1`.

**Comment by [hammel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21716/hammel/) on 2015-02-26**:
Thanks for your answer. I saw this line also in "rviz /Tutorials / Markers: Points and Lines" and tried it. Unfortunately without any success.
I also tried to change the type to `Marker.LINE_LIST` because i just want to have a single line --> no success :(

**Comment by [hammel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21716/hammel/) on 2015-02-26**:
Everything is fine. I had a lazy bug in my code, which was a little different from the posted. The above code works as it should.Thank you anyway :)

**Comment by [Sleipnir](https://answers.ros.org/users/108829/sleipnir/) on 2022-06-22**:
Hello I know this is kinda old but i've got the same problem of having nothing showing in rviz even so my code is structured as the answer.

My data is correctly published on the topic and i can select the topic of type marker in rviz but nothing shows.
Thanks for helping.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2022-06-22**:
@Sleipnir this is not a discussion forum, it is a Q&A site. If you have a question, please open a new question. See https://wiki.ros.org/Support for more.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2022-06-22**:
@Sleipnir I've deleted your answer and reposted as a comment. I had to remove the code snippet because it was too long to fit as a comment.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2022-06-22**:
@Sleipnir if you are confident you are publishing the marker (which you did indicate), I'd suggest you verify that:

- You've explicitly filled out the `marker.header.stamp` with a current timestamp (if the `lifetime` is non-zero this is required)
- You've set `rviz` to use the same fixed frame that your marker is using for a `frame_id` (or that there is a known transform from the marker `frame_id` to the fixed frame used by `rviz`
- Make sure the topic in `rviz` for the Marker display is set correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example code on how to publish a line (LINE_STRIP) as a marker

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point

rospy.init_node('line_pub_example')
pub_line_min_dist = rospy.Publisher('~line_min_dist', Marker, queue_size=1)
rospy.loginfo('Publishing example line')

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    marker = Marker()
    marker.header.frame_id = "/my_fixed_frame"
    marker.type = marker.LINE_STRIP
    marker.action = marker.ADD

    # marker scale
    marker.scale.x = 0.03
    marker.scale.y = 0.03
    marker.scale.z = 0.03

    # marker color
    marker.color.a = 1.0
    marker.color.r = 1.0
    marker.color.g = 1.0
    marker.color.b = 0.0

    # marker orientaiton
    marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
    marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
    marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
    marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

    # marker position
    marker.pose.position.x = 0.0
    marker.pose.position.y = 0.0
    marker.pose.position.z = 0.0

    # marker line points
    marker.points = []
    # first point
    first_line_point = Point()
    first_line_point.x = 0.0
    first_line_point.y = 0.0
    first_line_point.z = 0.0
    marker.points.append(first_line_point)
    # second point
    second_line_point = Point()
    second_line_point.x = 1.0
    second_line_point.y = 1.0
    second_line_point.z = 0.0
    marker.points.append(second_line_point)

    # Publish the Marker
    pub_line_min_dist.publish(marker)

    rospy.sleep(0.5)
```

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2017-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4